# Embedding Secure Grafana Dashboard to Angular Component

Tags: typescript, iframe, grafana, angular10

I’m new in grafana,I build a dashboard with grafana and I would like to know if I can embed my grafana dashboard into my angular application. I will really appreciate if someone can share with me any tutorial that explains how to do it.
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Running Grafana or any of it’s components in another React/Angular/... application is not officially supported. One common way to accomplish it is to embed an existing Grafana instance in an iframe. You’d then be able to set up a dashboard to use streaming.

But you can make you custom component and trigger DB. For make the Graph you can you charJS.